# ReactJS Dialog with close button

Tags: reactjs, popup, modal-dialog

I want to add close button to my react pop up so I added this line

```
 <button onClick = {$('.scoreboard-trigger').close}>Close</button>
```

but when I clik Close button it does not close

here is my all component

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';

import { FormattedMessage } from 'util/IntlComponents';

import OkeyScoreboard from './OkeyScoreboard';

class OkeyScoreboardDialog extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $('.scoreboard-trigger').leanModal({
      opacity: 0
    });
  }



  render() {
    const { scoreboard, profiles } = this.props;
    const scoreboardTitle = <FormattedMessage message="room_title.scoreboard"/>;

    return (<div id='scoreboardModal'
         className='scoreboard-modal modal'>

       <div className='modal-content'>
            <h4 className='center'>{scoreboardTitle}</h4>
          <OkeyScoreboard profiles={profiles} scoreboard={scoreboard}/>
                 <button onClick = {$('.scoreboard-trigger').close}>Close</button>
      </div>

      <div className='modal-footer'>

      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}


class OkeyScoreboardDialogTrigger extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const scoreboardTitle = <FormattedMessage message="room_title.scoreboard"/>;

    return <a className='scoreboard-trigger modal-trigger btn blue-grey darken-3'
              href='#scoreboardModal'>
      {scoreboardTitle}
    </a>;
  }
}


export { OkeyScoreboardDialog };
export { OkeyScoreboardDialogTrigger };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should wrap this in function

```
$('.scoreboard-trigger').close
```

in function and pass it to onClick method in button,
I create the example wrap it in function close and pass it to the onClick

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';

import { FormattedMessage } from 'util/IntlComponents';

import OkeyScoreboard from './OkeyScoreboard';

class OkeyScoreboardDialog extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $('.scoreboard-trigger').leanModal({
      opacity: 0
    });
  }
  close() {
     $('.scoreboard-trigger').close;
  }


  render() {
    const { scoreboard, profiles } = this.props;
    const scoreboardTitle = <FormattedMessage message="room_title.scoreboard"/>;

    return (<div id='scoreboardModal'
         className='scoreboard-modal modal'>

       <div className='modal-content'>
            <h4 className='center'>{scoreboardTitle}</h4>
          <OkeyScoreboard profiles={profiles} scoreboard={scoreboard}/>
                 <button onClick = {this.close()}>Close</button>
      </div>

      <div className='modal-footer'>

      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}


class OkeyScoreboardDialogTrigger extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const scoreboardTitle = <FormattedMessage message="room_title.scoreboard"/>;

    return <a className='scoreboard-trigger modal-trigger btn blue-grey darken-3'
              href='#scoreboardModal'>
      {scoreboardTitle}
    </a>;
  }
}


export { OkeyScoreboardDialog };
export { OkeyScoreboardDialogTrigger };here
```

Comment: this not work.I copy this but when click cose it does not close.I delete:here in last line of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [reacjs-popup](https://react-popup.elazizi.com/) A simple react popup component ( 3kb)

Comment: why are you using jquery with react?